# IText with Powershell to save each page to text

Tags: powershell, itext

```
$pdfReader = [PdfReader]::new($pdfName);
$pdfDocument = [iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument]::new($pdfReader);
$totalPages = $pdfDocument.GetNumberOfPages();
[ITextExtractionStrategy] $strategy = [SimpleTextExtractionStrategy]::new();
for ($p = 1; $p -le $totalPages; $p++) {   
   $page = $pdfDocument.GetPage($p);
   $text = [PdfTextExtractor]::GetTextFromPage($page, $strategy);
   $fileout = $pageHoldTempDir + $textVersion + $p + ".txt";  
   $text | Out-File $fileout | format-Wide;   
   $text = "";
}
$pdfReader.Close();
```

I am wanting to take each page in a PDF and write only the contents of that page to a dynamically named text file ($fileout).

If there are 6 pages in a pdf there will be 6 text files. However it appears to be appending the contents of each subsequent page despite creating a new page for each pdf page. $text = "" does not clear out the variable so the appending must be happening further up the chain?

Any

Comment: As an aside: `Out-File` produces no output, so `| format-Wide` has no effect. Also note that `;` is only ever needed for terminating (separating) statements if you place _multiple_ statements on the _same line_.

Comment: How many files are you getting as a result and how does `$totalPages` look like?

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon I ave 63 in my lastest sample and I have 63 text files in the directory after running the script.